# jQuery UI tabs - "remove" tab not working as expected

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

My jQuery UI version is "1.8.24" and I have issue using the remove method. I have thee tabs and as far as I know, they are 0-based indexed.

I have look thought other similar questions and I am using this code to remove the second tab:

```
$("#tabs").tabs('remove','1');
```

but the last tab is removed either. Actually, no matter what i index used:

```
 $("#tabs").tabs('remove','1');
 $("#tabs").tabs('remove','2');
 $("#tabs").tabs('remove','100');
```

always the last tab is removed.

Any ideas what is causing this? And something more interesting, I was not able to found this method described in the UI tabs documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't the second parameter be a number? jQuery is probably evaluating the String `'1'` and `'2'` to be the integer `0`.

If you don't have control of the data source (e.g. you're getting it out of the DOM), do:
`$("#tabs").tabs('remove',parseInt('1'));`

otherwise just use the correct data type:

`$("#tabs").tabs('remove', 1);`